# Why does my Regex.Replace string contain the replacement value twice?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string: `aWesdE`, which I want to convert to `http://myserver.com/aWesdE.jpg` using `Regex.Replace(string, string, string, RegexOptions)`

Currently, I use this code:

```
string input = "aWesdE";
string match = "(.*)";
string replacement = "http://myserver.com/$1.jpg";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, match, replacement,
          RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

The result is that output is ending up as: `http://myserver.com/aWesdE.jpghttp://myserver.com/.jpg`

So, the replacement value shows up correctly, and then appears to be appended again - very strange.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually 2 matches in your Regex. You defined your match like this:

```
string match = "(.*)";
```

It means match zero or more characters, so you have 2 matches - empty string and your text. In order to fix it change the pattern to

```
string match = "(.+)";
```

It means match one or more characters - in that case you will only get a single match

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. `(.*)` just matches anything. And since it is greedy, it will eat all in one.

Comment: @PatrickHofman If you run `Regex.Matches(input, match);` with above parameters you will see that there are actually 2 matches (`aWesdE` and empty string). They are used during the replace, that's why there are strange results when using `Replace`.

Comment: You are right. I tested your solution. Feels strange though. +1

Comment: Its not the `.*` that causes the 2nd match but the capture group `( )`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Are you sure about that? `Regex.Matches("aWesdE", ".*")` gives 2 results (empty and full text) and `Regex.Matches("aWesdE", ".+")` gives just a single result.

Comment: If pattern is `.*` then no group is captured and `$1` in replacement pattern is inserted verbatim. `(.*)` captures 2 groups and `(.+)` captures 1 group. Strange world.

Comment: It's not the grouping causing this effect as "Hello" -Replace '.*','x' in PowerShell generates "xx" as the output. I'm with Patrick, it feels strange