# Using nlog replace layout renderer, replacement seems to be done twice instead of once

Tags: nlog

I'm attempting to use the NLog Replace Layout Renderer (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-Layout-Renderer). I want to use it to truncate over-long messages. It seems to be able to do so, but replacement happens twice rather than once.

In my nlog.config, I'm using the following:

```
<variable name="replaced_message" value="${replace:searchFor=.*:replaceWith=Replaced:regex=true:inner=${message}}"/>

<target name="filelog" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/../logs/webapp/${shortdate}.log"
    layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}|${level:uppercase=true}|${machinename}|T:${threadid}|${logger}|${replaced_message}"/>
```

And I'm getting log entries like:

```
2015-03-04 13:41:14.337|INFO|T:11|ReplacedReplaced
```

Does anyone have an idea why the message is "ReplaceReplaced" rather than "Replaced"?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this problem has nothing to do with Nlog. It's just the regular expression that is the problem - identical to the problem found here:

[Why does my Regex.Replace string contain the replacement value twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081446/why-does-my-regex-replace-string-contain-the-replacement-value-twice)

There are actually 2 matches to the regex ".*".

The * means match zero or more characters, so there are 2 matches - empty string, and the text.

Changing the pattern to ".+" instead of ".*" resolves the problem. ".+" means match one or more characters so it no longer matches the empty string.

This kinda messes with my head, but it does appear to work that way.

And by the way, just in case anybody was interested in doing the same thing as my original plan, to truncate the Nlog message to 500 characters, it can be done using the following in nlog.config:

```xml
<variable name="truncated_message" value="${replace:replaceWith=...TRUNCATED:regex=true:inner=${message}:searchFor=(?&lt;\=.\{500\}).+}"/>

<target name="filelog" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/../logs/jobs/${shortdate}.log" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}|${level:uppercase=true}|${truncated_message}"/>
```

Comment: NLog 4.6.3 allows you to truncate using `${message:truncate=500}`